# Changes in compiler?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

For a project `VB.Net` that used to work on `Visual Studio 2017`, I upgraded to `Visual Studio 2019`, both versions still use .Net version 4.5.1.

Some code which used to run fine in VS2017, but in `VS2019` it gives an exception:

```
Dim highUId As Integer = alarmNw.Descendants().Max(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("UId").Value))
```

Where `alarmNw` is an `xElement` which contains a bunch of descendants, some of which have the `UId` attribute, some don't. The value of the UId attribute is always an integer value.

A mock version of the data can be generated with:

```
Dim alarmNw As XElement = New XElement("Main", New XElement("Sub1", New XAttribute("UId", 1)), New XElement("Sub2"))
```

The error message is: `Reference not set to instance of an object.`

I cannot find anything about this in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes).

This problem is can of course be fixed by changing it to:

```
Dim highUId As Integer = alarmNw.Descendants().Where(Function(y) y.Attribute("UId") IsNot Nothing).ToList() _
                    .Max(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("UId").Value))
```

If this changed what else has changed? Is there a list of which types of problems to expect?

Comment: Is it possible that alarmNw contains different data?

Comment: @the_lotus No, I tested on exactly the same source data.

Comment: What is the exception message? (P.S. probably nothing to do with this, but remember to set Option Strict On as the default for new projects as that setting doesn't seem to get carried over.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I editted the question for this: 'Reference not set to instance of an object'. Option Strict was also off in VS2017.

Comment: if x.Attribute("UId") or x.Attribute("UId").Value was null for any of the records this shouldnt have worked in the first place

Comment: Can you provide an example that can be replicated? At the moment we don't know what alarmNw is

Comment: @Ctznkane525: I understand that it was not neat in any way, but fact is that it did work.

Comment: I confirm that this throws `NullReferenceException` in VS 2017 / FW 4.5.1.

Comment: @DrDonut If it is using Option Strict Off, then unfortunately it is free to do as *it* wishes. You should always expect problems in that case.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Option Strict Off could not have an effect here, it may result in type errors but not in an NRE. Indeed, the NRE shows up here regardless of Option Strict setting.

Comment: @GSerg I may have been overly distraught that Off is still the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate this in both VS2017 and VS2019 both using framework 4.5.1

The code I ran is

```
 Sub Main()

    Dim alarmNw As XElement = New XElement("Main", New XElement("Sub1", New XAttribute("UId", 1)), New XElement("Sub2"))

    Dim highUId As Integer = alarmNw.Descendants().Max(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("UId").Value))

    Console.WriteLine(highUId)

    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

I get a null reference in both IDEs, so I suspect something else has changed.

Comment: Please don't use string literals for XML in VB. VB has XML literals. `Dim alarmNw = <a><b UId="1"/><b UId="2"/><b/><b UId="3"/></a>`.

Comment: @GSerg I've updated my answer to reflect the code in the question.

Comment: Thank you! Any clue what this other thing might be? It was also on a new virtual machine, but with the same software installed...

Comment: @DrDonut. I'm not sure what has changed but if you don't use .value and instead use CStr() you can get this to not error.

`Dim highUId As Integer = alarmNw.Descendants().Max(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(CStr(x.Attribute("UId"))))`

Although this isn't exactly _nice_ code